# Script BAT para identificar status do programa e iniciá-lo caso não esteja sendo executado

Tags: windows, script, bat

Tenho uma máquina que roda um programa de radar térmico e constantemente esse programa fecha sozinho.
Preciso de um script que identifique o status do programa e se ele não estiver sendo executado que seja iniciado instantaneamente.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8725/103217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso, no caso o batch procura por um processo a cada 10 segundos mais você pode mudar o intervalo e o programa pelo qual ele deve procurar e iniciar caso já não esteja rodando.

```
@echo off

::Coloque aqui o caminho para o programa:
set Programa=C:\Windows\notepad.exe

For %%a in ("%Programa%") do set "Processo=%%~nxa"

:Loop
cls
echo.
echo  Procurando:  %Processo%
tasklist |find /i "%Processo%" 1>nul 2>nul
if not %Errorlevel% EQU 0 start "" "%Programa%"
timeout /t 10 >nul
goto :Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode tentar dessa maneira também,
basta trocar as partes que estão com aspas
para o nome do processo do programa
e o caminho dele.
(remova as aspas depois de alterar)

se você iniciar o script com o programa rodando,
ele fará a verificação de 10 em 10 segundos

se você iniciar o script com o programa fechado,
ele iniciará o programa em 3 segundos sempre que
identificar que o programa se encontra fechado.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:main
cls
setlocal
tasklist /nh | findstr /i "notepad.exe"

if !errorlevel! EQU 0 (
echo. programa rodando ...
timeout /t 10 /nobreak &goto main
) else (
echo. iniciando programa ...
timeout /t 3 /nobreak
"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
goto main
)
endlocal
```